# How can I join in Laravel to get data?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working with Laravel 5 and I've the following models

Group.php

```
class Group extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ([
    'id'
    ]);

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            'App\User',
            'user_group'
        );
    }

    public function posted(){
        return $this->hasMany(
            'App\PostGroup'
        );
    }
}
```

PostGroup.php

```
class PostGroup extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'group_id', 'user_id', 'post_content'
    ];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function group(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Group');
    }

    public function commented(){
        return $this->hasMany(
            'App\PostComment'
        );
    }
}
```

PostComment.php

```
class PostComment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'post_id', 'user_id', 'comment_content'
    ];

    public function post(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\PostGroup');
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}
```

Contextually, my web application presents `groups`, in which you can create `posts` and to which post you can write `comments`. So, I have the following relationships in my database:

- Group: (id, name, description);
- PostGroup: (id, group_id, user_id, post_content);
- PostComment: (id, post_id, user_id, comment_content);

**What I want to do is** to create a list of PostComment objects, and then make a query **to get all the comments of all the posts of a group**, in MySQL looks like:

```
SELECT post_comment.* FROM post_comment,post_group WHERE post_comment.post_id = post_group.id AND post_groups.group_id = 1;
```

Now, for example, in Laravel if I wanna get all the posts of a group I've the following code line:

```
$postList = Group::find($id)->posted->sortByDesc('created_at');
```

Where `posted` is a function in Group Modal. I tried to do something like

```
$commentList = PostGroup::where('group_id', $id)->commented;
```

But it doesn't work, how can I solve?

**EDIT**

GroupController.php

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    // Replace with shares of publication-group-model
    $authUser =  Auth::user();
    $sharesList = Group::find($id)->shares->sortByDesc('created_at');
    $groupList = $authUser->groupsAsMember->where('id', '<>', $id);
    $group = $authUser->groups->find($id);
    $postList = Group::find($id)->posted->sortByDesc('created_at');

    $postsGroups = PostGroup::where('group_id', $id)->with('commented')->get(); 

    //dd($postsGroups);

    foreach ($postsGroups as $postGroup) {
        $commentsList = $postGroup->commented;
    }

    //dd($commentsList);

    return view('Pages.Group.detail', ['sharesList' => $sharesList, 'groupList' => $groupList, 'theGroup' => $group, 'postList' => $postList, 'commentsList' => $commentsList]);
}
```

Comment: You need to get the data using `->get();`

Comment: @Saurabh could you write me the entire code line please?

Comment: I have posted an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// This doesn't work because you can't call `commented` on a query builder
$commentList = PostGroup::where('group_id', $id)->commented;
```

Here's one way to do it using the relationship:

```
// Eager load the commented relationship
$postsGroups = PostGroup::where('group_id', $id)->with('commented')->get();

foreach ($postsGroups as $postsGroup) {
    $comments = $postGroup->commented;
}
```

If you don't want to loop through or even need the PostGroup's, then you need to join the PostComment table to the PostGroup table so that you can access the `post_groups.group_id` column.

Comment: I've just a little problem with your solution: since I need to send $comments to an HTML page like this: `return view('Pages.Group.detail', ['sharesList' => $sharesList, 'groupList' => $groupList, 'theGroup' => $group, 'postList' => $postList, 'comments' => $comments]);` $comments is empty when I send it to the HTML page, how can I solve?

Comment: Also, you should fix it because every loop cycle you go to overwrite the content of $comments

Answer (score 2):

Eloquent's [HasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship is designed for this kind of situation to allow access to distant relations:

```
class Group extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            PostComment::class, 
            PostGroup::class, 
            'group_id', 
            'post_id',
            'id', 
            'id'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an often overlooked function but is the best answer to this question. It would probably work with just `$this->hasManyThrough('App\PostComment','App\PostGroup')`. The documentation is here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
$id = "1"; //suppose
$postsGroups = PostGroup::where('group_id', $id)->with('commented')->get(); //this will give you a collection

dd($postGroups); //check this first

//with every loop, add comments to the comment collection    
foreach ($postsGroups as $postGroup) {
    $comments = $postGroup->commented;
    dd($comments); //check  if you are getting the data
}
```

Regarding another question from the comments: (Below code will give you some idea)

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;   // use this to create new collections

     $id = "1";
     $postsGroups = PostGroup::where('group_id', $id)->with('commented')->get();

     $comments = new Collection();
     //now you can loop through the object to get the values

     foreach ($postsGroups as $postGroup) {
         $coms = $postGroup->commented;
         $comments->push([
                'comments' => $coms,
                ]);
     }
     return view('index', array(
            'comments' => $comments,
        ));
```

Comment: Your solution has only one problem: since I need to send $comments to an HTML with this code line `return view('Pages.Group.detail', ['sharesList' => $sharesList, 'groupList' => $groupList, 'theGroup' => $group, 'postList' => $postList, 'comments' => $comments]);` $comments is empty when I send it to the HTML page, I think it's because $comments is in a foreach loop, I tried to do `$comments;` before the foreach but it doesn't work, how can I solve?

Comment: You need to create a collection or an array to store the comments and inside the for loop, you need to push every comment to your collection/array you created earlier. After that you can pass the collection/array to the view. And in the view, you can run a for loop to display the comments.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let me know the output you are getting.

Comment: I'll try, if you want I updated my answer and insert the edit of the code

Comment: I tried and unfortunally it doesn't work, take a look at my controller edit